# Accepting Chef Infra Client license agreement for version >= 14

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm trying to bootstrap a node using chef by using the command `knife bootstrap <host> --ssh-user '<username>' -i <my-identity>.pem --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name <node-name> --run-list 'recipe[<cookbook-name>::default]'`

However, its failing because I can't accept the license

```
4 -----> Existing Chef installation detected
137.252.24.94 Starting the first Chef Client run...
137.252.24.94 +---------------------------------------------+
137.252.24.94             Chef License Acceptance
137.252.24.94
137.252.24.94 Before you can continue, 2 product licenses
137.252.24.94 must be accepted. View the license at
137.252.24.94 https://www.chef.io/end-user-license-agreement/
137.252.24.94
137.252.24.94 Licenses that need accepting:
137.252.24.94   * Chef Infra Client
137.252.24.94   * Chef InSpec
137.252.24.94
137.252.24.94 Do you accept the 2 product licenses (yes/no)?
```

And I can't input the answer from the host machine. I used to be able to run the `chef boostrap` command easily before chef 14.0. It seems like they upgraded to Chef 14.0 and the new upgrade has a mandatory requirement for the license agreement. How do I agree the license into the client machine from the host machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, based on my findings, this problem can occur in two different scenarios:

1. When you're running the `kitchen converge`. This can be solved very easily by adding a piece of code inside the `kitchen.yml` as

   ```
   provisioner:
     client_rb:
       chef_license: accept
   ```
2. When you're running the `knife bootstrap`, this can be a little bit of extra work. This [page](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#custom-templates)  explains all that needs to be done. Inside the `.chef` directory.

```
> mkdir bootstrap
> cd bootstrap && touch template.erb
> find /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby -type f -name chef-full.erb -exec cat {} \; > template.erb
```

Find the line that part that says

```
cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP
<%= config_content %>
EOP
```

and replace it with

```
cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= config_content %>
chef_license "accept"
EOP
```

Next, run the command `knife bootstrap <host> --ssh-user '<username>' -i <my-identity>.pem --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name <node-name> --boostrap-template "template" --run-list 'recipe[<cookbook-name>::default]'`. That took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below line to accept license.

```
chef-client --chef-license accept  > /dev/null
```